# Create, save, and read text file

Tags: ios, file-management, text-files

I want to open one blank new text file on a button event, edit the text, and save it in a directory, and also read that file at any time.

Answer (score 6):

You can read a text file into a string with this method on NSString:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
                  usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc
                         error:(NSError **)error
```

You can write it again with:

```
 - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path 
          atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile 
            encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc 
               error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: Is it possible any way to open .txt file in iPhone App?

Comment: Yes. The methods I just posted will let you do that.