# Create and read a text file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text-files

I am looking to create a text file on my iPhone programmatically and also write some data onto the file. How can I read the text file manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create text file & save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123284/create-text-file-save)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSString`'s `initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` to read the file, then use `stringByAppendingFormat:` to add some data, and then use `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` to write it on disk.

Comment: hi thanks i was checking through this, but where can i find the file on my iPhone??

Comment: In the user's Document directory : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272544/whats-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-documents-directory-on-an-iphone

Comment: i mean can i view the file manually. And where is this Document directory located??

Comment: No you can't view the file manually on a device. You need to access it programatically.

Comment: I am actually writing an application, where i need to write some data to a log file in the form of a .txt or .gpx file. So later the user can read the file manually or use it basically. Do you know of anyway i could do this??

Comment: Add it in you app's bundle and read it from there. You'll need to write in the document directory since writing from your bundle is not possible.

Comment: hi i am sorry for asking too many q, i am trying to understand somethings, could you please tell me how i could add it in the app's bundle and read it ??

Comment: Hi nevermind, i found an iPhone Explorer to get the .txt file from the Documents directory.. Thanks for your support