# Reading a text file and turning it into a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added a text file to Xcode, now I want to make a string with it. How do I load it and put it into a string?

`NewsStory1.txt` is the file, and I'm using Obj-C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create, save, and read text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123284/create-save-and-read-text-file)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63983/can-i-delete-my-own-question

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewsStory1" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

See Apple's iOS API documentation for [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring#1666632), specifically the section "Creating and Initializing a String from a File"

Comment: You can also just pass a string as the path directly `stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/your/file"`

Answer (score 5):

In swift

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("home", ofType: "html")

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)} catch _ as NSError {}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Very Simple**

Just create a method as follows

```
- (void)customStringFromFile
{
    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewsStory1" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *stringContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"\n Result = %@",stringContent);
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer posted 4 years earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 this can be done like this:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test_data", ofType: "txt")
if let path = path {
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(content)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error occured: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
} else {
    print("Path not available")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another simpler way with Objective-C:

```objectivec
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"<paht/to/file>"
                     enconding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error: &error];
```

Comment: This is simpler because you left out the part for obtaining the path. Otherwise this is the same as other answers.